# How to open a non modal dialog in Prism 8

Tags: wpf, prism

I am using Prism 8 WPF and I can't find a way to open a NON-modal dialog. All the dialogs in Prism seem to be modal.

Comment: A non modal dialog is a window, because a modal window is a dialog :o) or in other words: being modal is the only thing that makes a dialog a dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Show`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/7f0b1680bbe754da790274f80851265f808d9bbf/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Services/Dialogs/IDialogService.cs#L11) method of `IDialogService` for non-modal dialogs.

```
/// <summary>
/// Shows a non-modal dialog.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">The name of the dialog to show.</param>
/// <param name="parameters">The parameters to pass to the dialog.</param>
/// <param name="callback">The action to perform when the dialog is closed.</param>
public void Show(string name, IDialogParameters parameters, Action<IDialogResult> callback)
```

The alternative for showing a modal dialog is the [`ShowDialog`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/7f0b1680bbe754da790274f80851265f808d9bbf/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Services/Dialogs/IDialogService.cs#L29) method. See [Dialog Service](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/dialog-service.html) in the Prism documentation for details how to implement a dialog and use the `IDialogService`.